# How to make a hierarchical categories of a view's nodes?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to have hierarchical categories of a view's nodes,where categories will be taxonomy terms of the nodes.How to do that?

Comment: Your going to have to be a little more specific on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Whats is **view's nodes**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your taxonomy as tree, and insert nodes having given term, into that tree, you'd need [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree). This adds a display plugin for Views. You just need to create a node listing view which accepts a term argument.

If you mean to format the term attached to a node, as a hierarchical tree, try [Term Reference Tree](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

Comment: There is a problem with views integration.